# Converting JSONL response to collection/List in Zoho CRM Deluge

Tags: zoho, zoho-deluge

so I am trying to work with a 3rd party API which returns a JSONL response:

```
{"Key1":"Value1","Key2:Value2"}
{"Key1":"Value1","Key2:Value2"}
..so on
```

Now I want to convert this to a list of individual JSONs to process with for-each loop but I am unable to do so with in-built functions in Deluge.
Is there any way to do so?

I have tried toCollection("\n") and toJSONList() but both of them dont work. This mainly due to Deluge treating the response a contineous single string/text and hence no new lines in text.

I had expected it t return a list of JSONs:

```
[{"Key1":"Value1","Key2:Value2"},
{"Key1":"Value1","Key2:Value2"}]
```

Comment: Please include your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this may work.

```
//----------------------------------------------------------------------    
// Create a list by splitting on each JSON item's ending curly bracket.   
// This removes the curly bracket so it will need to be added back later.     
//----------------------------------------------------------------------       
response_list = response_jsonl.toList("}");

//----------------------------------------------------------------------    
// Add back the curly-bracket removed in the split.   
// Convert to Zoho Map and display keys.  This is just to verify it works.    
// -  If it works change the code to do the desired action on the data.     
//----------------------------------------------------------------------    
for each item in response_list
{
    item_json = item + "}";
    item_map = item_json.toMap();
    info item_map.keys();
}
```

Comment: I used a similar approach, and it worked for me. Thanks for your help